# Is there a "never ask me about cookies again" cookie that we can set?

Tags: feature-request, support, cookies, cookie-policy

While I know it's in vogue to consider everything, everyone, and everywhere a lethal threat to one's well being, I have a question of a different sort.

StackExchange is a plague of "we use cookies" pop ups. Since each site is a unique domain, we get the privilege of accepting cookies `e v e r y w h e r e`.

Not only are they everywhere, they seem to come back even after I've accepted them. And they seem to come back a lot.

I don't habitually purge my cookies, or my history, etc.

Yet, there they are again -- more cookie pop ups. My login is reset, etc.

So.

I was wondering if there's a `*.stackexchange.com` cookie we can have to quiet this down. (I'd make a similar posit for the huge WELCOME banners on all of the sites just because I don't happen to be logged in.)

I've been coming here for years, pretty sure I'm good with SE cookies et al. Y'all seem like good folk.

It would be great if there was a destination with a Big Red Shiny Button, and maybe an "are you sure" checkbox that lets us carte blanche the *.SE sites. Wildcard the kit AND kaboodle.

"Please SE, never ask me about cookies again!"

Anything that can be done here?

Comment: Most of our sites share the same domain. Only about five differ. Are you getting this on every stackexchange.com site or just on SO, SF, SU, etc.

Comment: To expand on what Catija said, we *do* already use a global cookie for all our sites, minus the domain-specific ones if your browser doesn't support cross-domain cookies, so there isn't anything to complete here because this feature already exists (we only ask you about cookies once a year). If this is consistently breaking for you and logging you out, then something's going wrong inside your browser. Which one are you using? Any extensions that might be interfering?

Comment: It's most noticeable on the SE site, since there's so many (just clicking on the various Hot Network Questions, for example). Safari 12.1.1 and AdBlock.

Comment: @animuson I sometimes get this on *.stackexchange.com sites, even if I'm logged into another *.stackexchange.com site. I always get it on cross-domain SE sites. Safari 15.3 (17612.4.9.1.8) with zero extensions.